# Force 404 error when extension is added to URL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, url-mapping

I need some help with URL mapping, in my code when i go to:

```
http://localhost:8080/register.asdf
http://localhost:8080/register.asddsdsd etc.
```

it always returns `http://localhost:8080/register` but I want to make it *404 NOT FOUND*.
How can I fix this?

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {    
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  
    ctx.register(Config.class);  
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);    
    Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));  
    servlet.addMapping("/");  
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
}
```

}

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

@RequestMapping(path = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String registerGet(Model model) {

    return "register";
}
```

**EDIT :** i added following code in Config.java and solved thanks.

```
@Override
public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict your mapping changin the `@RequestMapping` or the `servlet.mapping`. 
Change RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/register.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)//for example
```

Or servlet.mapping:

```
servlet.addMapping("*.htm");
```

**EDIT:**
If you are using Spring 4.X you can use this:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:path-matching suffix-pattern="false" />
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: is there anyway without inserting extension?

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-path-matching) use below config to restrict the unwanted extensions

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:path-matching suffix-pattern="false" />
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```